# How to remove repository from sources.list using bash command?

Tags: text-processing, repository

I have Ubuntu 16.04 x32.

The backports repository is enabled by default.

```
deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

How to add `#` on the beginning of this row? I would like to disable this by bash command only.

Please help :-)

Comment: Is `sed` allowed even though it's not a `bash` built-in command?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed '/xenial-backports/{s/^/#/}' sources.list
```

This will find all lines containing the string `xenial-backports` and for each of those lines put a `#` character in front of the line.

Output will be on the console.  Redirect to a file, inspect that file to make sure it's correct, and move it into place.

Alternatively,

```
$ sed -i '.old' '/xenial-backports/{s/^/#/}' sources.list
```

This will back up the old file in `sources.list.old`.

Comment: You could make an even better answer by including `ed` and `ex` as well.

Comment: @JdeBP Well, yes, editing the file by hand would be easy. You could probably even write a elisp script for Emacs to do it as well. The next step up would be having someone else write the script for you, which is what is happening.

Comment: I've tried your command but as a result terminal showed me the original file, without changing anything. I have added -i and . and now it works like a charm. sudo sed -i '/. xenial-backports/{s/^/#/}' /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @anthony0013 That's what I said it would do (display it on the console). The entries ought to have been changed though, but it may be hard to spot if there a lot of output. Your modification of the regular expression makes no sense. You're also running it without creating a backup, which is unsafe.